# Windows 10 - SSH connection timeout

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssh

I have strange issue on my Windows 10.

I use Putty and WinSCP - on both clients the connection is closing after X amount of minutes of inactivity.

Is there a way of getting rid of this timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection may be terminated by the server for inactivity, rather than by
the program.

**PuTTY keep connections alive**

- Load your connection session.
- In the Category pane, click Connection.
- Under "Sending of null packets to keep session active",
  in the "Seconds between keepalives", type 240 for 4 minutes (or less).
  PuTTY will now send a packet to the server every 240 seconds to keep the
  connection alive.
- In the Category pane, click Session.
- Click Save.

**WinSCP keep connections alive**

- When connecting, enter the
  [Advanced Site Settings dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_connection)
- In the Keepalives section, choose an appropriate method
- Click OK.

Comment: That worked. I was convinced that it was Windows TCP that was terminating the connection.